# getting records in database using getdate method

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am currently running a query but can't see the issue

I want to get the records from 11/14/2016 to present date 
i can definitely run my first query but I wanted to use the getdate() method to get the records until present day (today's date)
So i tried my second query but i get an error.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20

Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
    WHERE ( (ct.ServiceDate >= '11/14/2016') and (ct.ServiceDate <= '01/01/2017')  ) 
   and ct.ProgType = 'CMP'  and ct.Route !='NA' AND TimeIn IS NOT NULL AND TimeOut IS NOT NULL AND EntryUser IS NOT NULLde here




WHERE ( (cta.ServiceDate >= '11/14/2016') and (cta.ServiceDate <= GETDATE())  ) 
   and cta.ProgType = 'SchoolProgram'  and cta.Route !='NA' AND TimeIn IS NOT NULL AND TimeOut IS NOT NULL AND EntryUser IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The error message looks like SQL Server, so I removed the MySQL tag.  And why do you have `ct` in the first snippet but `cta` in the second?

Comment: Data type of cta.ServiceDate?

Comment: `..EntryUser IS NOT NULLde here` ?

Comment: better off using `BETWEEN` like `cta.ServiceDate between '11/14/2016' and GETDATE()`